# Meteor call / livedata

Tags: meteor

How can I process some logic before each `Meteor.call` ?

I've tried to redefine `Meteor.call` at startup in the package but it didn't work as expected, I could process the logic within each `Meteor.methods` but I would like to keep it D.R.Y.

Comment: What did you try to do with `Meteor.call` and what was the result? I'd also start by redefining that method, so let us know what have you done already and why didn't it work.

Comment: i am trying to write a generic Acl package, for it to work without too much code once add to a project (hence keeping it DRY) i need to process the checking logic before each Meteor.call(). If i redefine the call method it work only @ startup and somehow meteor redefine it back to its original state !